# Primefaces paginator selected button is not changing

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

So when Im trying to click 25 or 50, that amount of rows is displayed but selected button is still 12, what can be wrong?
[image: Paginator display]

```
<p:dataTable id="X_Y_Z" value="#{pSB.pDB}" var="prv" widgetVar="prvtab" emptyMessage="#{lbl.no_data}"
           paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
           paginatorTemplate="{header} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"              
           rowsPerPageTemplate="12,25,50" rows="#{pB.getNumber('P_BLNC')}"
```

Comment: Is your dataTable nested in a form?

Comment: @JasperdeVries yes it is

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Although you have not included {RowsPerPageDropdown} in the paginatorTemplate in your example, I am going to suppose that you have included it in your code. Anyway, modify the rows property and assign it to a variable (ensure that you create the getter/setter). Eg: #{pSB.rows} which is a "int" or Integer. Currently, your rows variable always return the same value.